# Can I select a color for each text line I append to a TextView?

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have a TextView to be used as a bluetooth connection console. When I send a command, I want it to be written in a color (for example cyan), and the answers received in a different color (for example red).

Is it possible to do that, and if so, how?

I read it may be possible to do using HTML, but i'm not quite sure it is the best approach, or even how to do it.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939862/textview-with-background-color-and-line-spacing/30096905#30096905

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you really need it to be a TextView or can you use a ListView instead and add a new row in the list for each command/answer?

If you *really* want to use a TextView you can do something like this (This is a working example you can just copy and paste to your app to try out):

```
package com.c0deattack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MultipleColoursInOneTextViewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        String command = "This is a command";
        String response = "\nThis is a response";

        tv.append(command + response);
        Spannable spannableText = (Spannable) tv.getText();
        spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, command.length(), 0);
        spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), command.length(), command.length() + response.length(), 0);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.addView(tv);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

So that shows that it can be done, but you'll obviously notice you'll have to set the line breaks yourself and workout where each command/answer starts and ends so you can apply the correct colour to it. It's not that hard but to me, feels clunky.

Comment: I wanted to use a TextView because it looks like a console terminal. A ListView has horizontal lines between each 2 lines, so it wouldn't look like that. If you know how to avoid those lines, it could work for me. Please explain how if you know how to.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a little helper function based on C0deAttack's answer, that simplifies things

```
public static void appendColoredText(TextView tv, String text, int color) {
    int start = tv.getText().length();
    tv.append(text);
    int end = tv.getText().length();

    Spannable spannableText = (Spannable) tv.getText();
    spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end, 0);
}
```

Just replace any calls to

```
textView.append("Text")
```

with

```
appendColoredText(textView, "Text", Color.RED);
```

Comment: Could you please explain me why this solution no longer works if a prebuild ForegroundColorSpan object is passed instead of the color parameter? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's easyer if you use:

```
textView.append(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void appendColoredText(TextView tv, String text, int color) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    ssb.append(text);
    ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, text.length(), 0);
    tv.append(ssb);
}
```

optimizing [@benjymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9400875/1336154) answer

we can create a `SpannableStringBuilder` object to hold the `text` and the `color span`, and use its `append()` and `setSpan()` methods to add the text and the color span.

This will be more efficient, as it avoids creating a new Spannable object every time the method is called.

Answer (score -3):

check for every state 
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Comment: wouldn't that change all the written text, both tx and rx, to the color I'm giving?

Comment: I think it will too. This solution isn't satisfying at all.