# How to add line spacing after every "\n" in a string in android?

Tags: android, html, string, newline, spacing

As the question is clearly stated, I want to add a small line spacing after every `\n` defined in a string in a resource file in Android.

Let's say we have a string defined in xml like this:

```
<string name="line_test">This is the 1st line. This is still the 1st line.\nThis is the 2nd line.\nThis is the 3rd line. This is still the 3rd line.\nThis is the 4th line.</string>
```

The normal output when setting it to a `TextView` will be like the left side of this image. What I want to achieve is the right side of this image.

[image: Image 1]

There are some attributes in xml like:

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
```

and

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
```

but these attributes will only lead to something like this:

[image: Image 2]

So I don't want to add line spacing after every new line because the width of the line is consumed, but only after every defined `\n`.

Any way to achieve what I want through code or html? By saying html, I mean something like this, but with some modified stuff after adding `<br/>`:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is the 1st line. This is still the 1st line.<br/>This is the 2nd line.<br/>This is the 3rd line. This is still the 3rd line.<br/>This is the 4th line."));
```

It is more like I want to create many paragraphs in the `TextView` with small line spacing after each paragraph all in one string. I thought that this would be possible to be done through HTML, so that's why I added html tag.

---

**Edit:**

I also don't want to add two line breaks because I only want a small line spacing, and putting two line breaks together will have a large line spacing, which I don't want due to some design issues in my app.

Comment: Why don't you give two line breaks? **\n\n**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
public String addNewLine(String string) {
    int count = string.split("\n", -1).length - 1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(count);
    String[] splitString = string.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
        sb.append(splitString[i]);
        if (i != splitString.length - 1) sb.append("\n\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. There is no even multiple lines. It only transformed the whole string into a single line.

Comment: try with "\n" and tell me

Comment: Nothing changed. The whole string is still in one line.

Comment: Ok now i have to leave later ill try another strategie

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I have modifed your code a little bit. I think I will have to add two line breaks rather than one line break because this is the simple solution. I will have to fix my layout though and suite it to the needs. I accepted your answer because it helped me to reach what I wanted. ;)

Comment: A pleasure to help such a young and talented programmer :)

Answer (score 5):

What about giving two line breaks like this

```
<string name="line_test">This is the 1st line. This is still the 1st line.\n\nThis is the 2nd line.\n\nThis is the 3rd line. This is still the 3rd line.\n\nThis is the 4th line.</string>
```

In case of `HTML` use two `<br/>` tags

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is the 1st line. This is still the 1st line.<br/><br/>This is the 2nd line.<br/><br/>This is the 3rd line. This is still the 3rd line.<br/><br/>This is the 4th line."));
```

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that I don't want to add two line breaks because I only want a small line spacing, and putting two line breaks together will have a large line spacing, which I don't want due to some design issues in my app. I edited the question now. However, I up-voted your answer because it is still definitely correct. Thanks for your answer.