# How can I highlight the textview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, frontend

This is what I have done!

```
spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.highlightColor)), 0, div.getText().length(), 0);
textview.setText(spannableString);
```

Result Achieved!

[image]

Desire Result!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Finding the solution on your own? That's the reason someone gave you a -1.

Comment: simply use textview.setBackgroundColor()

Comment: now, give a look to the edited questions! I hope it clears all the doubt!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939862/textview-with-background-color-and-line-spacing ... maybe this helps you ;-)

Comment: it does not have the solution @jennymo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you: [Can I select a color for each text line I append to a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105545/can-i-select-a-color-for-each-text-line-i-append-to-a-textview)

But instead of the `ForegroundColorSpan` try using the `BackgroundColorSpan`

Comment: BackgroundColorSpan also highlight the vertical margin between the lines!